# Site activity monitor

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

Could there be a graph or indicator somewhere on this site to show activity during the day? It seems that one has better luck getting answers if they post during active times so this could be a good feature for users that want quick(er) answers.

Comment: If users' really do get substantially greater visibility for their questions when deliberately posting them in such a way as to *make the site even busier when it's busiest*, then that seems like a site bug that should be corrected. With that said, I think a site activity monitor could be quite useful, especially if it shows some detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moderators have access to such tools and can monitor site traffic, posts, type of posts, accesses, etc.

I do not see how that would be interesting to a normal user and since the measuring is done on top of the SE servers it would create a lot of pressure on top of busy servers.

I do not think that posting a question in a busy time attracts more views as posting an answer in busy times has better chances to get up votes.

You get greater visibility by posting a good quality question, with details and effort to be assisted.

You get greater visibility by posting a good quality answer, with direct, clear instructions and a good explanation on how that would solve the issue.

Unless there is a direct, more specific reason why this should be implemented I do not see any reason for it to happen.